# I am gettting an error while trying to implement a basic example of vue-echarts library

Tags: vue.js, echarts

I am trying to use the vue-echarts wrapper for the echarts library

I get an error (`"Error: xAxis "0" not found"`), while trying to implement a simple example found [here](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple):

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
import { use } from "echarts/core";
import { CanvasRenderer } from "echarts/renderers";
import { LineChart } from "echarts/charts";

import {
  TitleComponent,
  TooltipComponent,
  LegendComponent
} from "echarts/components";

import VChart, { THEME_KEY } from "vue-echarts";

use([
  CanvasRenderer,
  LineChart,
  TitleComponent,
  TooltipComponent,
  LegendComponent
]);

export default {
    name: "HelloWorld",
    components: {
        VChart
    },
    provide: {
        [THEME_KEY]: "light"
    },
    data() {
        return {
            option: {
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'category',
                    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
                },
                yAxis: {
                    type: 'value'
                },
                series: [{
                    data: [150, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147, 260],
                    type: 'line'
                }]
            }
        };
    }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it may be this line:

[image]

`myChart.setOption(option);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think that the vue-echarts wrapper makes the option initialization for you, so you can omit this step.